# python pandas keep rows with values that match csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with a column containing subject IDs (data['id'] in this dataframe). I want to only keep the rows in which the subject ID matches a value from my txt file (subjects_visit2.txt). I tried doing this with .isin but I get all 'False' when that is not true. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Also, after it's fixed and I get some 'True' values, how do I print the values and not just 'True'?

```
# load list of subjects I want to keep
subject_list = pd.read_csv('maskave/Visit2/subjects_visit2.txt')
subject_list = list(subject_list)

# read csv i want to cut
subjInfo = pd.read_csv('maskave/amyg_PFC_correlations.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(subjInfo)

# restrict to subject IDs in txt file
new_df = data['id'].isin(subject_list)

print(new_df)
```

edit: subject_list is a one-column text file with numerical values. when i convert it to a list, it becomes only the first value for some reason.

Comment: `new_df=data.loc[data['id'].isin(subject_list),:]`

Comment: data['id'].isin(subject_list) is a boolean series. You could simply use `data[data['id'].isin(subject_list)]` to use the "mask" and filter out the rows.

Comment: Im not sure if the mask needs to be the part which is removed or the part that is kept. Could you clarify?

Comment: When I try either of those solutions I get an empty dataframe. 

@PaulaLivingstone I want to keep the values that are True (which match a value from subject_list)

Comment: Are you sure there actually are any exact matching strings? If so, you need to print(subject_list[new_df])

Comment: my txt file is one column of numbers. when I change it to a list, only the first value remains. I think that's causing the issue

Comment: got it-- your responses worked when I fixed my list!